# Is it possible to save Windows process state to file and after restarting it to load the same state?

Tags: windows, process

In some situations, it will be very useful to save the state of a process to file and to be able to load the state at a future point in time to continue from exactly the state which was saved. Is it possible to save Windows process state to file and after restarting it to load the same state?